# Azure Functions does not load when an extension library is referenced

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to get a near empty (2.0) dotnet core functions project to serve up the default page inside a container. Everything is fine until I add an extension (such as service bus). I add the extension like so:

```
func extensions install --package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus --version 3.0.2
```

However this appears to do NOTHING else but add a package reference to the project. When i try and start the project (func start) i get "The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed." When I do the same in a container I don't get any of that output (which is super annoying) and if I browse to the app i get "The function host is not running".

Also when I build under ./bin I have an extensions.json file with an empty array in it. For some reason i then have another bin folder (./bin/bin) with an extensions.json file in it that is correctly populated with the extensions I have added.

Answer (score 1):

Removing this package

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.0.1" />`

Resolved all my runtime extension problems.